# Return or skip from catch in async function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, asynchronous

I have a async function whose output (resolve/reject) I translate with then/catch.

I want to end the outer function with return but I can only return within catch somehow.

How can I skip/quit/return on the outside of catch or await?

```
await this.authService.auth(this.oldUser).then( resolve => {

  //went in authService and resolve can be used

}).catch( reject => {

  //in catch as authService rejected and want to return to outer 
  //function

  return;
})

//Second attempt should only be done if first attempt "resolved"
await this.authService.auth(this.newUser).then( resolve => {

}).catch( reject => {

  return;
})
```

Comment: Keeping in mind to the tagging suggestion from StackOverflow, are "AngularJS" and "Angular" essential to the question?
`use tags that describe things or concepts that are essential, not incidental to your question`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have the `.then` and `.catch` return something meaningful that distinguishes them, and then test that distinguishing factor. For example:

```
const result = await this.authService.auth(this.oldUser).then((authorizedUser) => {
  // do stuff with authorizedUser
  return authorizedUser;
}).catch((err) => {
  // handle errors, if needed
  return { err };
});

if (result.err) {
  // there was en error, return early:
  return;
}
// rest of the code that depends on the first request being successful goes here
await this.authService.auth(this.newUser).then(...)
```

Note that if you're using `await`, it might make a bit more sense to use `try/catch` rather than `.then`s *and* `await`s:

```
try {
  const authorizedUser = await this.authService.auth(this.oldUser)
  // do stuff with authorizedUser
  // rest of the code that depends on the first request being successful goes here
  const newAuthorizedUser = await this.authService.auth(this.newUser);
  // do stuff with newAuthorizedUser
} catch(err) {
    // handle errors, if needed
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private async authenticate(oldUser: User) {
    try {
        await this.authService.auth(this.oldUser).toPromise();            
        return;
    } catch (reject) {
        return;
    }
}
```